# How to upload more than 1 image to AWS S3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

As per title, how do I upload more than 1 image to AWS S3? I'm able to successfully upload 1 image into my AWS S3 bucket. However, my app allows users to upload up to three images, and is there a way not to specify the bucket, and `AWSTransferManager` again for three times?

```
let uploadRequest: AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
uploadRequest.bucket = "mybucket"
uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACL.PublicRead
uploadRequest.key = "media/uploads"
uploadRequest.contentType = "image/png"
uploadRequest.body = url

let transferManager: AWSS3TransferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()

transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: {(task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject! in
     if task.error != nil {
          print(task.error)
          NSLog("Error uploading : " + uploadRequest.key!)
     }
     else {
          NSLog("Upload completed")
     })
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a function that takes in the key as the parameter and creates the request?

Comment: Because the `transferManager.upload` is uploading my image async. Which is why I'm afraid that my first image is still in the process of upload, i need to declare the upload key again for second image, which I'm not too sure if it is "safe" to do so or not.

Comment: Unless the object keys are same, it's safe.